# How to control and 12v DC solenoid with gpio pins?

Tags: pi-4

I am looking for a way to power something like this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1512, without breaking my raspberry pi 4 b. I want to use GPIO pins for this. How can I do this properly? Do I need an adapter of some type? I am new to this so thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't drive a solenoid *directly* with a GPIO pin. You will need an **interface** between the GPIO and the solenoid. The [technical details](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1512#technical-details) necessary to design this interface were provided on the product page the linked in the question.

Shown below is a representative schematic with the interface you'll need (components R1, Q1, and D1):

- Q1 should be a Darlington NPN transistor as you'll need high current gain to control the solenoid with a GPIO pin.
- R1 limits the base current supplied by the GPIO to Q1 - it should be sized to allow approx 10-15 mA.
- D1 is a suppression diode to protect Q1 from the "inductive kick" generated by halting the flow of current through the coil in the solenoid. Use a [Schottky diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode) here.

I'll assume you have the 12V power source in hand.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6KJ4w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: Some suggestions for components D1, R1 & Q1:

- D1: [1N5819](https://www.onsemi.com/products/discretes-drivers/diodes-rectifiers/schottky-diodes-schottky-rectifiers/1n5819)
- R1: 150
- Q1: [TIP112](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip110-d.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Get an H-bridge motor driver board (e.g. L298N), connect your solenoid to "motor" terminal, and use a single input pin to control it. If you can live with 9V instead of 12, there are lots of smaller and cheaper motor drivers which work below 10V (like DRV8833).

There's also TA6586 chip which is suitable for hand soldering if you prefer DIY:

[image]